# ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP when retrieve data from procedure in webform (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a procedure in oracle that returns a cursor. When I execute my proc in SQL Navigator it works well, but when I call the procedure in C# it returns the following error:

```
Description: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

Could I fix this error from Oracle or C#? Many thanks for somebody who tells me some advice about this bug!

Comment: You ran out of space in the temporary database. This can often mean you have a query that is doing something intensive like cross joining or ordering. Are you absolutely certain you are running the same query? When you execute the proc in SQL Navigator, are you actually using the cursor that is returned?

Comment: As the previous comment indicated, Oracle is using the temp tablespace to build a transitional data set that is too big to hold in memory - as with a table join or sort. The explain plan of the query would tell you for sure what it is doing there. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html#GUID-60E30B1C-342B-4D71-B154-C26623D6A3B1. There is not really a "code" fix for this, other than to modify your SQL. You will either need to tune your SQL to be more efficient, or increase the size of the temp tablespace.

Comment: There is usually only one temporary tablespace, so there's a chance that another user or another query is causing the problem, and that your error is only a symptom and not the cause. You may need to ask your DBA for assistance in tracking down the processes using temporary tablespace. For example, I often use a query like this to look for temp tablespace hogs: `select * from gv$active_session_history where temp_space_allocated > 1024*1024*1024;`

Comment: can you provide the query you send to oracle? maybe it is bad plan for your sql statement.

Comment: I rewrote my sql then it worked successfully. Many thanks the support from all. Thank you very much.